# Cmake could not find Boost (missing python) (found version 1.73.0)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am on `Windows 10`, `Visual Studio 2019`, `cmake 3.17.3`, `boost 1.73.0`. I am trying to install `Geant4` (particle simulation toolkit), and one of the dependencies for building the program in `cmake` is `boost-python`.

I installed boost, but I am still getting the following error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.73.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:45(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
environments/g4py/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

Could the problem have to do with my system path? I think I added boost to my path, but I may have done it wrong because there were 50 different tutorials saying to do 100 different things. Maybe I need to add a pointer to boost-python specifically? I am not familiar with `cmake` or `boost` (or c++ for that matter) so playing with the path is the only idea I have right now.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, have you installed Python library of Boost or not? If you don't know what have you installed, you may look into documentation.

Comment: It should be installed. I just ran b2 which from what I can tell builds all of the libraries including python. Is there more to the installation than that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cmake could not find boost\_python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067518/cmake-could-not-find-boost-python)

Comment: The Cmakelists.txt are all provided as part of the Geant software, so that is likely not the problem. My best guess is there is a problem with my Boost installation that I can't figure out. Anyone know how to check if it's installed properly?