# cmake is unable to find boost python in conda environment

Tags: python, boost, cmake, anaconda, boost-python

I have trouble in installing a python package named `Fred`(https://github.com/derohde/Fred) in Ubuntu 20.04 which uses boost python. I build boost 1.73.0 from source using python 3.8.6 in a miniconda environment. I checked the boost python is compiled successfully, but cmake cannot find it.

```
boost: 1.73.0
python: 3.8.6
cmake: 3.17
```

The used cmake command is

```
 Command '['cmake', '/home/ubuntu/Program/Fred/py/..', '-DBPY=python3.8', '-DBNPY=numpy38', 
'-DBOOST_ROOT=~/boost', 
'-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=~/boost/lib', 
'-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/ubuntu/Program/Fred/py/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/Fred', 
'-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/bin/python', 
'-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']'
```

Part of the output of cmake message is:

```sh
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/bin/python (found version "3.8.6")
-- Found PythonLibs: /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/lib/libpython3.8.so (found version "3.8.6")
CMake Warning at /snap/cmake/580/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2007 (message):
  No header defined for python.; skipping header check (note: header-only
  libraries have no designated component)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)


CMake Error at /snap/cmake/580/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python.) (found suitable version "1.73.0",
  minimum required is "1.63")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/cmake/580/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /snap/cmake/580/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2166 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56067518/681865 -- you probably have to modify the build to explicitly nominate a python version

Comment: @talonmies Thanks so much. It works. I spend several days to find the problem. It is because I changed the authors `CMakeLists.txt`.